# How to find laplace of int(x(t),t,0,t) in Matlab?

Tags: math, matlab

is it possible to find the laplace of an integral of x(t), and that integral is bounded between 0 and t?

```
>> laplace(int(x(t),t,0,t))
??? Undefined function or variable 't'.
```

I should get the answer something like this:

```
X(s)/s
```

Comment: Are you looking for the Laplace transform?

Comment: I know the function 'laplace', but is it possible to apply it on that integral?

Comment: If you integrate over `t`, you can not use `t` as a bound.

Comment: @Time But there is a rule that says: laplace(int(f(t),t,0,t)) = F(s)/s

Comment: Read closer; some t's are probably \tau. You could see it as indefinite integration over the positive numbers.

Comment: @Tim, of course you can use `t` as the upper bound. In this case, the integral is a function which gives you the area under the curve from `0` till `t`, instead of just a value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use MATLAB's symbolic toolbox, you should set the variable to be a symbolic object using the `sym` function like this: `t=sym('t');`

**EXAMPLE:**

```
t=sym('t');
laplace(int(exp(t),0,t));
```

output: `1/(s - 1) - 1/s`

Comment: But I'm asking for x(t) not exp(t)

Comment: @Eng.Fouad This was just an example. You will have to define the function `x(t)`. If you were expecting it to solve for a generic function `x(t)`, without defining it, you're using the wrong tool. You should probably use Mathematica/Maple. Remember, MATLAB's symbolic math toolbox is rudimentary. So if you need to work in terms of arbitrary functions, you'll need to provide additional information as to whether the function bounded on the interval [0,∞) or locally integrable on the same interval, etc., all of which are necessary for the transform to exist. This is not possible (AFAIK) in MATLAB.

Comment: @yoda: Actually, MATLAB will in this situation perform a more formal computation (which is, in the end, the primary reason it's called “Computer Algebra” and not “Computer Calculus”). At least in simple situations like this one, that boils down to “if the input is defined, then the result is defined, too, and it's this.”

Answer (score 1):

As yoda said, you need to declare your symbolic variables, and for a symbolic `x(t)` without further information, that means using `sym('x(t)')`.

To avoid confusion between the two actually very different `t` in your input, I'd relabel one of them, say, to `u`. (MATLAB works fine without doing that, it's just for readability for humans.)

```
>> syms s t v
>> laplace(int(sym('x(v)'),v,0,t))  
Warning: Explicit integral could not be found.  

ans =

laplace(x(t), t, s)/s
```

Now, if you want to teach the system that the Laplace transform of `x` should be `X`, I'm afraid you'll need to resort to MuPAD syntax (the symbolic computing engine behind the Symbolic Math Toolbox):

```
>> syms s t v
>> evalin(symengine, 'transform::laplace::addpattern(x(t), t, s, X(s))')
>> laplace(int(sym('x(v)'),v,0,t))  
Warning: Explicit integral could not be found.  

ans =

X(s)/s
```